# Magento2 Order status is getting set to pending when partial refund is done from processing

Tags: magento2, order-status

Magento2 Order status is getting set to **pending** when partial refund is done from **processing**

This happens only in case of store pickup & not in case of home delivery.

Please suggest how to move forward I need to keep status to processing